# remainder: $\lfloor 1^p/p \rfloor + \lfloor 2^p/p \rfloor... + \lfloor 2015^p/p \rfloor$ divided by p

Tags: number-theory

Let p = 2017.
Find the remainder when

> $\lfloor 1^p/p \rfloor + \lfloor 2^p/p \rfloor   + \lfloor 3^p/p \rfloor + .... + \lfloor 2015^p/p \rfloor$

is divided by p.
How do I solve this **number theory** question using **Fermat's Little Theorem**? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: And your efforts?

Comment: I'm sorry. I already figured that \floor n^p/p = (n^p-n)/p. But after that, I couldn't figure out how to find the remainder mod 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n^p\equiv n\pmod p$ for all $n=1,2,\dots,p-1$, we have
$$n^p=\lfloor n^p/p\rfloor p+n,$$
from which
$$\sum_{n=1}^{p-2}n^p=p\sum_{n=1}^{p-2}\lfloor n^p/p\rfloor+\sum_{n=1}^{p-2}n,$$
whence
\begin{align}
S
&=\sum_{n=1}^{p-2}\lfloor n^p/p\rfloor\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{p-2}\frac{n^p-n}p\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{(p-1)/2}\left(\frac{n^p+(p-n)^p}p-\frac{n+(p-n)}p\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{(p-1)/2}\left(\frac{n^p+(p-n)^p}p-1\right)\\
\end{align}
Since $(p-n)^p\equiv -n^p\pmod{p^2}$, we get
\begin{align}
S
&\equiv -\sum_{n=2}^{(p-1)/2}1\\
&=-\left(\frac{p-1}2-1\right)\\
&=-\frac{p-3}2\\
&\equiv\frac{p+3}2\pmod p
\end{align}
For $p=2017$ we obtain $S\equiv 1010\pmod{2017}$.

Comment: Thanks. I for some reason wanted to reduce n+ (p-n) = p as zero first, instead of dividing by p to get 1. That is wrong though.

Comment: Why is (p-n)^p == -n^p mod p^2? Also why are we using p^2 instead of p here? is it because we are dividing by p twice

Comment: This follows by binomial formula. I reduce by $p^2$ first because I have to divide by p.